# Calculate amounts in grouped array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a new array of people with their total amounts. I was able to filter out people based amounts. Could anyone please help?

```js
mockData = [{
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Gas',
  amount: 20.10
}, {
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Taco bell',
  amount: 4.10
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Food',
  amount: 30.50
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Groceries',
  amount: 10.20
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Paint',
  amount: 5
}];

const distinctItems = [...new Map(mockData.map(item => [item.name, item])).values()].map(({
  name
}) => name);

const filterTotals = (expenses, person) =>
  expenses.filter(({
    name
  }) => name === person)

const result = distinctItems.map((name) => filterTotals(mockData, name));

console.log(result)
```

The end result I'm expecting is

```
[{name: 'John', total: 24.20}, {name: 'Doe', total: 45.7}]
```

Comment: a reduce function should work excellently there

Answer (score 2):

You could take a single loop with the data and add `amount` to the same `name`.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'John', title: 'Gas', amount: 20.10 }, { name: 'John', title: 'Taco bell', amount: 4.10 }, { name: 'Doe', title: 'Food', amount: 30.50 }, { name: 'Doe', title: 'Groceries', amount: 10.20 }, { name: 'Doe', title: 'Paint', amount: 5 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { name, amount }) => m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + amount), new Map),
        ([name, total]) => ({ name, total })
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: May I know what are `set` and `get` functions here?

Comment: they are coming from the accumulator: [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the array to an object with key as the name & value as the total amount for that name & then you can use Object.entries to iterate over the key & value

```js
const mockData = [{
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Gas',
  amount: 20.10
}, {
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Taco bell',
  amount: 4.10
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Food',
  amount: 30.50
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Groceries',
  amount: 10.20
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Paint',
  amount: 5
}];

const obj = mockData.reduce((map, obj) => {
  const {
    name,
    amount
  } = obj
  map[name] = name in map ? map[name] + amount : amount
  return map
}, {})
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({
  name: key,
  total: value.toFixed(2)
}))
console.log('result', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
mockData = [{
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Gas',
  amount: 20.10
}, {
  name: 'John',
  title: 'Taco bell',
  amount: 4.10
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Food',
  amount: 30.50
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Groceries',
  amount: 10.20
}, {
  name: 'Doe',
  title: 'Paint',
  amount: 5
}];

const totalAmountMap = mockData.reduce((accumulator, { name, amount }) => {
    accumulator[name] = (accumulator[name] || 0) + amount;
    return accumulator;
 }, {});

 const totalAmountArray = Object.keys(totalAmountMap).map((name) => ({
     name,
     total: totalAmountMap[name]
 }));

 console.log(totalAmountArray);
```